# Words in a word cloud triggering actions?

Tags: graphics, button, hyperlink, word-cloud

I'm wondering if it's possible to set actions to the words in a WordCloud. I'd like to press a word and have it printed. I noticed [here](https://ref/WordCloud) that Button[] can be used like ToolTip[] so changed the example code

```
entities = EntityValue[CountryData[], {"Name", "Population"}];
WordCloud[{Tooltip[#[[1]], #[[2]]], #[[2]]} & /@ entities]
```

into this but didn't work 'cause strings were expected. Then I thought that maybe an hyperlink would work but this only works with URL, right?

```
WordCloud[{Button[#[[1]], Print[#[[1]]]]} & /@ entities]
```

Thank's for your help

Comment: try `WordCloud[{Button[#[[1]], Print[#[[1]]]]} & /@ entities]` or  `WordCloud[{Button[#[[1]], Print@ #], #[[2]]} & /@ entities]`

Comment: Thank's, the second option worked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The elements of the input list should be of the form {Button[$string_i$, $action_i$], $weight_i$} or,for unweighted data, just Button[$string_i$, $action_i$]. So

```
 WordCloud[{Button[#[[1]], Print@#], #[[2]]} & /@ entities]
```

works as expected:

[image]

You can remove the braces around `Button[...]` in your code to get an unweighted word cloud:

```
WordCloud[Button[#[[1]], Print@#] & /@ entities]
```

[image]